# Azure Function Change Feed from CosmosDB JavaScript

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-iot-hub

I would like to achieve following scenario in Azure.

Simulated IoT device sends some messages to IoT Hub and I store it in CosmosDB. So far this thing is working. I used Azure Function to achieve that.

Next step is to create new Azure function with change feed triger from CosmosDB and push it to Azure Event Hub.

I created in portal apropriate **function.json**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHub",
      "name": "outputEventHubMessage",
      "connection": "dev-euwest_all_EVENTHUB",
      "eventHubName": "forwardedmessages",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "cosmosDBTrigger",
      "name": "inputDocuments",
      "connectionStringSetting": "cdb-euwest_DOCUMENTDB",
      "databaseName": "iot",
      "collectionName": "messages",
      "leaseCollectionName": "forwardedmessages",
      "createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists": true,
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Then I have the **index.js**

```
module.exports = async function (context, documents) {
    if (!!documents && documents.length > 0) {
        context.log('Document Id: ', documents[0].id);
    }
}
```

When I run it there is no failure but I don't see any document id.

This is my sample source message using Azure IoT Python device [Azure Python Simulator](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-python/blob/master/iot-hub/Quickstarts/simulated-device/SimulatedDevice.py)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da47cd2b19c571e106a040c"),
    "temperature" : 34.78470937343868,
    "humidity" : 79.96610016503291
}
```

What I am doing wrong here? How can I pickup the messages correctly?

Comment: can you add more details on how you are sendng the message to cosmosdb/eventhub

Comment: I am using function which fetch the message from IoT device simulator (link above) and push it to CosmosDB. It has _id, temperature and humidity in body (as above). This part is working. The not working part is fetching the stored messages from CosmosDB (probably the **index.js** code is wrong) because the Event Hub messages are empty.

Comment: Why don't you simply set up a second route to send the IoT hub incoming messages directly to the Event Hub? Probably cheaper than running a second function too.

Answer (score 1):

The sample document is a Bson document. Which means that you are using a Cosmos DB account with Mongo API.

If that is correct, please check the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-functions), which states that:

> Currently, the Azure Functions trigger for Cosmos DB is supported for use with the Core (SQL) API only.

Also, in the [Azure Functions Binding documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#supported-apis), it states:

> Azure Cosmos DB bindings are only supported for use with the SQL API. For all other Azure Cosmos DB APIs, you should access the database from your function by using the static client for your API, including Azure Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB, Cassandra API, Gremlin API, and Table API.

Currently, the Trigger does not support Mongo.

Answer (score 0):

CosmosDB change function checks only if the document was updated and triggers a call.